# installing codeigniter on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: php

i have a running `apache` `mysql` `php` xampp server on `ubuntu 13.10`
my path `/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/www`
the correct path or directory inside `/opt` to unzip CI files

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: @WolfgangVogl i mean can i make a directory inside `/opt` for ci files to work. i mean i have already `/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/www` where my .php files are.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As i think your "CI" Files are the CodeIgniter files and this is a php framework - so you have to store this files in your webdir - the "www" directory of apache. I thought this is /var/www but if you tell me its /opt/lamp/htdocs/xampp/www when this is the document root of your apache... (i just use nginx).
Of course you can loacte your web directory everywhere you want, its simple apache configuration.